# ul ul li a not responding to color

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, hover, html-lists

Hey I am trying to make the:

`ul ul li a` in a `nav` color `#FFF`

but no matter what I do I can not change it I think it may be that the:

`ul li a` is affecting it however that's `#FFF` to?

My goal is white text on a dark background and then black text on a white `hover`.

here is my code so far:

CSS:

```
nav ul ul li

{
    background: #4a4a4a;
    float: none; 
    position: relative;
   color: #FFF;
}

    nav ul ul li a 

{
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px 51px;
}

    nav ul ul li a:hover 

{
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our Prices</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Consulting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Quick Hire</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Any help would be great thanks :).

Comment: Can you post your HTML? Try making your selectors more strict: `nav > ul > ul > li`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all likelyhood, these are URLs you've already visited, which causes the browser to display them in different colours.

Add `a:visited` instead of just `a` to the CSS selector.

```
nav ul ul li a, nav ul ul li a:visited
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to achieve the same here:

**[JSbin Demo](http://jsbin.com/esogij/5/watch)**

```
    nav ul ul li
    {
     background: #4a4a4a;
     float: none; 
     position: relative;
     color: #FFF;
    }

    nav ul ul li a 
    {
     color: #FFF;
     padding: 0px 51px;
    }

    nav ul ul li:hover
    {
     background: #FFF;
    }

    nav ul ul li:hover a
    {
     background: #FFF;
     color: #000;
    }
    nav ul ul li a:hover 
    {
     background: #FFF;
     color: #000;
    }
```

Comment: It works in an example but I cannot make it work in the script?